# How to do large time series data sharpening/zooming for easier visualization using pandas?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, pandas

I need to visualize very large time series data. I want to do something similar to one shown here: [Zoomdata](https://www.zoomdata.com/product/fast-data-sharpening-visualization/) (that's where I got the term 'data sharpening').

Data example: every minute temperature data from thermostat.

I want to do web based viz and I think it should be pretty easy if I can get right kind of data from backend. Thus the question is, is it possible to do data sharpening using pandas or any other tools on large data?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the groupby function for different timescales  (min, hour, day, week, month, year, etc.) and use apply to average over the data. Or use max, or min, depending on what you want to see.

The timescales could be fed from the viz using a javascript control like a dropdown box.

You could also use the resample function on your groupby object.